# Difference between "on a global scale" and "at the global scale"

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

In the two sentences below, do "on a global scale" and "at the global scale" mean the same? Can the phrases be used interchangeably?

**(1)**

> Our collaborative team is strategically positioned to market this
>   ground-breaking, multiple-patented product **on a global scale**.

**(2)**

> The company has started the production effort needed to successfully
>   deliver a land cover product **at the global scale**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is: ***[on a global scale](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20a%20global%20scale)***:

> in relation to the entire world
>
> - The war could impact the economy on a global scale.

(M-W)

*At the/a global scale* is a less common, unidiomatic variant.

See [usage examples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20a%20global%20scale%2Cat%20the%20global%20scale%2C%20at%20a%20global%20scale&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20a%20global%20scale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20global%20scale%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20global%20scale%3B%2Cc0) here.